# How do I go about reading the value of a dice face using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and have been pondering this question for a while now but I can't seem to find the right solution. I was thinking template matching but then the template may not be the same scale as its occurrence in the input image or it may not be in the same orientation as its occurrence in the input image. The only other way I can think of is by finding all the black colored blobs within a certain distance of each other and getting the number of those blobs. If so how do i do this? If there is a better method please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: Try searching on StackOverflow for `[opencv] dice`

Comment: @Setchell thanks. Is there a way to close this thread? or do i just delete my post?